# Elastic Thumbnail menu - css not making bottom of images stick

Tags: javascript

I found a quick and easy animation technique to add to my thumbnail gallery, the technique is here http://buildinternet.com/2009/09/sproing-make-an-elastic-thumbnail-menu/

I have implemented with no issue however for me, the css doesn't appear to ensure the images stick on the same level like they should in the given demo example.

This means when I hover on an image and it enlarges, all the others move around too. I want it to work like the demo which is more of an 'apple-dock' type animation. please see code below:

and **[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7PRwA/2/)**

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.menuitem img').animate({width: 155}, 0);
     $('.menuitem').mouseover(function(){
       gridimage = $(this).find('img');
       gridimage.stop().animate({width: 200}, 500);
     }).mouseout(function(){
       gridimage.stop().animate({width: 155}, 300);
     });
  }); 
</script>
```

CSS

```
#menuwrapper{ 
   position:relative;
   height:210px;  
}  
#menu{
  position:absolute;
  bottombottom:0;
}  
.menuitem{ 
  position:fixed relative;
  bottom:0px; 
  display:inline-block; 
}  
img { 
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; 
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="menuwrapper">  
<div id="menu">  
  <a href="/interactive/cis/PaycoCISBrochure.html" class="menuitem">
    <img   class="interactive_img" src="/images/Payco-CIS-interactive.png">
  </a><!--Template for each menu item-->  
  <a href="/interactive/PU/PaycoUmbrellaBrochure.html" class="menuitem">
    <img class="interactive_img" src="/images/Payco-Umbrella-interactive.png">
  </a>
  <a href="/interactive/tech/PaycoTechBrochure.html" class="menuitem">
    <img class="interactive_img" src="/images/Payco-Tech-interactive.png">
  </a>
  <a href="/interactive/media/PaycoMediaBrochure.html" class="menuitem">
    <img class="interactive_img" src="/images/Payco-Media-interactive.png">
  </a>
  <a href="/interactive/medical/PaycoMedicalBrochure.html" class="menuitem">
    <img class="interactive_img" src="/images/Payco-Medical-interactive.png">
  </a>
  <a href="/interactive/logistics/PaycoLogisticsBrochure.html" class="menuitem">
    <img class="interactive_img" src="/images/Payco-Logistics-interactive.png">
  </a>
  <a href="/interactive/SU/SimplyUmbrellaBrochure.html" class="menuitem">
    <img class="interactive_img" src="/images/Simply-Umbrella-interactive.png">
  </a>
</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: prepare a jsfiddle and share it here.

Comment: I would do but it's not having the code, not sure why I can't replicate it on there. I get the images in a line but that's all. I shall look at it properly very soon and post for you.

Comment: @JohnFarrell See my answer. Also to get Jquery woking in jsfiddle you need to select `Jquery version ` in `frameworks and extension` option on Left TOP

Comment: Added original DEMO to question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks good. .

Here is **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7PRwA/2/)** for your Code .. I changed Nothing but Image URLS

If you mean by

> I want it to work like the demo which is more of an 'apple-dock' type animation.
>   the css doesn't appear to ensure the images stick on the same level like they should in the given demo

that the other images dont appear to be going down in DEMO but go down in your case...

you are having wrong menu style

```
 #menu{
  position:absolute;
  bottombottom:0;
}
```

Correct is

```
#menu{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
}
```

Here is **[Corrected DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7PRwA/3/)**

Comment: Added original DEMo to question too

Comment: I tried this earlier as I saw this error in the demo (forgot to enter the corrected css on here!) but doesnt work on my page so I guess there is some other issue with my code elsewhere. This is my page with the corrected css http://tinyurl.com/bmchjvf Firstly it should be below the text and secondly, it doesn't 'stick' to the bottom like your jsfiddle

Comment: do get it below text I think you need to add new div as a child of `further-left-interactive` in which you will have all the text... and then you will have `menuitems`

Comment: Thanks for the help with jsfiddel, sorted it now. Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mm013/dBE3R/ works fine as you say (well the top row of images does, I guess I need mor epadding to stop the next row pushing the top row) However exactly the same code on the actual page (the link I gave earlier tinyurl.com/bmchjvf) displays the images high on the page and covers the text plus they dont stick to the bottom like the jsfiddle

Comment: Even on the fiddle, it covers the last line of text

Comment: Updated your fiddle. I changed some CSS properties..Check.. Now working like charm..  http://jsfiddle.net/dBE3R/2/

Comment: That's made the images display where they should so that's great, thanks however I still don't get the effect of the bottom line of the images sticking to the same level. In the jsfiddle it is great but on the site it isn't. EDIT actually this latest jsfiddle is doing the same with the images not sticking however in your initial jsfiddlethis issue was fine

Comment: See this... just a tweak in CSS and JQuery animate... http://jsfiddle.net/dBE3R/3/
If i helped.. Please accept and upvote

Comment: Nearly perfect but the images are back at the top of the page again!

Comment: where are you seeing issue in latest jsfiddle in comment? o on your page only? if in jsfiddle which browser? its working on chrome

Comment: The issue was on the site, looked fine in jsfiddle. It must be the images as the actual images are much taller. That is when I get the issue. Here is the good jsfiddel with my images http://jsfiddle.net/mm013/dBE3R/4/

Comment: I added lots of padding to the menuwrapper and it is ok now unless you can think of a cleaner way of doing it? http://jsfiddle.net/mm013/dBE3R/5/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dBE3R/6/ ... just increase the div height ... no need for big padding.. As this answer solved your issue please accept as answer and if possible upvote